Import multipart GPG Key into Landscape
I'm trying to mirror the Google Chrome repository on my local on-prem Landscape (24.04.5) server.  I'm trying to import the GPG key but I keep getting an error.  The PUB can be found here: https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub and information about the signing key can be found here: https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
The command and error messages I get when trying to import are:
landscape-api import-gpg-key chrome ~/Downloads/linux_signing_key.pub

Got server error:
Status: 400
Error code: URLLimitError
Error message: API does not support URL length above 16382. Passing --method=POST may help.

I also tried with the --method=POST:
landscape-api import-gpg-key chrome ~/Downloads/linux_signing_key.pub --method=POST

Got server error:
Status: 400
Error code: MultipleGPGKey
Error message: Multiple GPG keys in material

The PUB file does contain 2 Keys and if I break them up I can import the top-most Public key however it's not enough to be able to sync the repository.
Does anyone have any ideas on what else I might try?
